# Gray-out the edit link on own comments after 5 minutes

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, live-refresh

I have a suggestion, if comment edits are not allowed after five minutes, then gray-out the *edit* link after that time. A tool-tip on the grayed-out link would explain why it's disabled.

I think this will be less annoying than clicking a normal-looking link and being chastised by an orange box.

Comment: There is no edit link after five minutes, only delete.

Comment: The edit button only exists after 5 minutes if you haven't refreshed or reloaded the page, and my understanding is comments are designed that this would not be possible to implement.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but if you never refresh the page it remains visible, (at)psubsee2003 how is removing a link not possible?, it should be nothing compared to update the _X mins ago_ every minute (which they somehow do)

Comment: @ajax333221 everything is possible, but the live refresh never removes or disables anything; it just update stats or let you know "something new happened".

Comment: The link does stick around after five minutes, as ajax333221 said.  We have JavaScript at our disposal.  This should be as simple as a loop that sleeps for N seconds at a time, then checks if it's time to change some attributes/elements.  This sort of thing is done all over the web.  It's not an unreasonable suggestion.

Comment: Note, we don't have to _literally_ deactivate the link.  There are other approaches to swapping out elements.  I'm not intimately familiar with web development, but I know enough to know this sort of thing is done.

Comment: I'm supporting the proposal and I'd upvote the question, if I had the reputation. I just edited a comment heavily and was confounded when I was clicked the "edit" button but was confronted with a "you can not edit" message immediately afterwards. The edit button needs to be removed/disabled/grayed out when the edit window has closed.

Comment: @D.Sachse you can upvote now! ;)

Comment: +1. This suggestion is over a year old, and nothing has changed, it seems.  It is extremely bad UI to show something as active and available that is not. Especially something like this. It would even be helpful to show the time left. Dunno how many times I've been bitten by this -- we should show a user how much time is left. 

And BTW, just why is it so important to close a comment to editing after 5 minutes?  What is the great problem that this restriction solves?

Comment: I prefer to receive a message that I can not change a comment before I start editing. I realize you have those situations where we start editing before the 5 minutes and exceed 5 minutes when we try to Save Edit. That requires a different solution?

Comment: The worst part is that one can spend effort editing the comment, only to be told at the end that it's too late to edit it.